# Mapster and Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mapster

I would like to plug and use Mapster in my Blazor project.
I can't find a good reference on how to register mappings and get them injected in the different layers of my application.

Does anyone know how do I achieve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be very simple.

Mapster exposes the IMapper interface that can be used to register a configuration, similar to the following:

*In Startup.cs*

```
var config = new TypeAdapterConfig();
config.NewConfig<ModelA, ModelB>()
    .Map(d => d.PropertyB, s => s.PropertyA);

var mapperConfig = new Mapper(config);
services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(mapperConfig);
```

Now you just need to inject the IMapper interface in your service and use it e.g.:

```
public MyService(IMapper mapper)
{
this.mapper = mapper;
}
...
var modelB = modelA.Adapt<ModelB>(mapper.Config);
...
```

This works perfectly, any thought/improvement is welcome!